# linux terminal animation - best way to delay printing of 'frame' (in C)

Tags: c, linux, animation, terminal

I'm working on a simple pong clone for the terminal and need a way to delay the printing of a 'frame'.

I have a two dimensional array

```
screen[ROWS][COLUMNS]
```

and a function that prints the screen

```
void printScreen() {
    int i = 0;
    int j;

    while(i < ROWS) {
        j = 0;

        while(j < COLUMNS) {
            printf("%c", screen[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

It seems that when I do

```
printScreen();
usleep(1000000);
printScreen();
```

it will `sleep` the execution *during* `printScreen()`.

Any tips for doing this type of animation on the terminal would be much appreciated. Maybe I'm doing this completely wrong. How is it done with ASCII movies [like this](http://www.junauza.com/2009/08/watch-star-wars-ascii-animation-via.html)?

**EDIT** I'm going with ncurses. Thank you both for the suggestion.

On Ubuntu `sudo aptitude install libncurses5-dev` and compile with `-lncurses`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ascii movies are done with aalib which works like a graphics display driver. Most people developing full fledged console apps and games use the curses framework or a version of it like ncurses. The one real restriction of going that route is you have to want the full ptty (you can't take part of it).

Answer (score 3):

stdout is buffered.  It won't actually send the output to the terminal device until it is told to print a newline or is explicitly flushed.

To flush the output, simply add:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Also, since all you're doing is printing a single character, printf is way overkill.  You can replace your printf with:

```
putchar(screen[i][j]);
```

Comment: Doh! putchar is much simpler. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you need to add `fflush(stdout);` before returning from `printScreen()`.  But there are much better (easier) ways of doing text animation, and terminal control.  Look at [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) for example.